# Change from Roles authorization to Claims authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-identity, roles, claims

I have a webforms application which was built with ASP.NET Membership. I migrated to Identities successfully.

I now want to use Claims authorization instead of Roles authorization, but the Role information for the old users has been migrated to the `AspNetUserRoles` table in the database but the `AspNetUserClaims` table is empty. New users registered after migration, I can add to `AspNetUserClaims` with the following code:

```
IdentityResult result1 = manager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "role"));
```

But the old users are only registered in the `AspNetUserRoles` table not in the `AspNetUserClaims` table.

1. On login will the claim created include Role information from the `AspNetUserRoles` table also or only from the `AspNetUserClaims` table?
2. Will the `User.IsInRole()` check both the `AspNetUserRoles` table and the `AspNetUserClaims` table?
3. How can I migrate information from the `AspNetUserRoles` table to the `AspNetUserClaims` table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get hooked on "claims" term. Here this is a convenient way to add information into the cookie.

Here actually are 2 types of "claims" - one that is added into the cookie and one that is preserved in `AspNetUserClaims` table.

When user is logging in, a cookie with identity is created. Identity contains all the claims user has. Claim here is a key-value pair that is added in the cookie as a payload. Cookie claims contains things like `User.Id`, `SecurityStamp`, `Username` some other framework related stuff and... list of roles from `AspNetUserRoles`. Along with additional claims from `AspNetUserClaims`.

So what you are trying to add roles into claims - makes no sense. Roles will be in the cookie as claims anyway - added by the framework.

Probably I'm not explaining well - when you debug your application, analyse `User` property of a controller and look into `ClaimsIdentity` and see list of all the claims. All my jibbering will make more sense.

To answer your second question - `User.IsInRole()` does not go into the database. This method only checks information in the cookie, see the [source code for yourself](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs,765): it only checks if cookie contains claims of type `ClaimTypes.Role` with the name of the role you are trying to check.

Third question... do you still want to do that? You can do a SQL statement, something like `insert into aspnetuserclaims (<columns>) select <columns> from aspnetUserRoles inner join aspnetroles on aspnetUserRoles.roleid = aspnetroles.id`.

I wrote about what claims go into the cookie [in my blog a while ago](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/aspnet-identity-and-owin-who-is-who/) - you'll get a better understanding how it all comes together.

Comment: This is very helpful and informative! Some of this I had started to unravel through debugging. Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understood you, concerning question 1, when registering a new user it's enough to register his role in the UserRoles table, there's no need to register his role in the UserClaims table. Is that correct?

Comment: @DovMiller Roles are roles, no need to put the same info into Claims. So you are correct here.